# How to create a timeline graph ( Date / time series) in MATLAB?

Tags: time-series, predictive-modeling, prediction, matlab, plotting

The data file is attached https://ufile.io/ttwi8.How may I create a timeline graph where my y-axis is the number of cases(Demand and prediction as sjown in attached graph)[image] and my x axis is increasing time of the day with the year?

```
  clc;
clear; 

data3=readtable ('PRICE_AND_DEMAND_Jan.csv')
    Date_Time = data3(:,2);
    datecell=table2cell(Date_Time);
    load = data3(:,3);
    A = table2array(load)
    p=datenum(datecell);
    plot(datenum(datecell), A)
    datetick('x', 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')
    % datetick('x', 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')
```